# Why am I only parsing one XML tag from a node.js express API POST?

Tags: xml, node.js, post, express

I'm having issues parsing more than one XML tag from the body of the response coming into my POST API. I can swap the placement of the text or affiliate tag within the request and the app always parses the top tag but not the other one. Any help is appreciated.

```
//Express
var app = express();
router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(xmlparser());

router.post('/api/v1/inboundData', function(req, res) {

var results = [];

// Grab data from http request
var data = {text: req.body.text, affiliate: req.body.affiliate};

// Get a Postgres client from the connection pool
pg.connect(connectionString, function(err, client, done) {
    // Handle connection errors
    if(err) {
      done();
      console.log(err);
      return res.status(500).json({ success: false, data: err});
    }

    // SQL Query > Insert Data
    client.query("INSERT INTO \"inboundData\"(\"data\", \"affiliate\") values($1, $2)", [data.text, data.affiliate]);

    // SQL Query > Select Data
    var query = client.query("SELECT * FROM \"inboundData\" ORDER BY \"ID\" DESC");

    // Stream results back one row at a time
    query.on('row', function(row) {
        results.push(row);
    });

    // After all data is returned, close connection and return results
    query.on('end', function() {
        done();
        return res.json(results);
    });
});
});
```

Contents of the body in the request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<text>blah</text>
<affiliate>xmltest</affiliate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your XML is invalid. There should be a single root element wrapping those two elements.

You can try validating it with http://www.xmlvalidation.com/. The error shown is:

> Errors in the XML document:
>   The markup in the document following the root element must be well-formed.

This XML should solve your problem:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<content>
  <text>blah</text>
  <affiliate>xmltest</affiliate>
</content>
```

I'm not sure, but you'll probably need to change the way you read the body in your javascript to this:

```
// Grab data from http request
var data = {text: req.body.content.text, affiliate: req.body.content.affiliate};
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. The XML I used does pass validation in the online tool, but I am getting better results using your method. A couple of questions, though. 1: when using your code the values that go into my db insert aren't the raw text strings, they include special characters around them like this: {\"blah\"}, {\"xmltest\"}. Before when I was posting with JSON only the string blah or xmltest would be inserted. Any ideas? Also, what would the equivalent JSON object look like for the xml you posted? I tried {"content": [
    {"text": "blah","affiliate": "xmltest"}
]}

Comment: How are you building the posted XML? It looks like those special characters are coming from the client. Can you confirmar that? The JSON equivalent for this XML is { "content": {"text": "blah","affiliate": "xmltest"} }, just like you typed, but without the brackets.